# Did Rasputin have an affair with Tsarina Alexandra Feodorovna?

Tags: history, russia, celebrities

[Grigori Rasputin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Rasputin) was a trusted friend of [Tsar Nicholas II of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_II_of_Russia) around 1915.

There is a popular rumour that he was having an affair with Nicholas's wife, [Tsarina Alexandra Feodorovna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Feodorovna_(Alix_of_Hesse))

Wiki briefly says:

> Iliodor, hinting that Rasputin was Alexandra's paramour, showed Makarov a satchel of letters, one by the Tsarina and four by her daughters written in 1909 and 1910.

Singing group, [Boney M.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boney_M.) obviously thought so, from their song "[Rasputin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasputin_(song))" where they described him as the "Lover of the Russian queen".

As far as actual historical research proves/disproves, did Grigori Rasputin have a sexual relationship with Tsarina Alexandra Feodorovna?

Comment: You can thank @Shog for putting that particular song into my head for the last 2 days.

Comment: This needs more context. Is the question is "Did Rasputin have an affair with Tsarina Alexandra Feodorovna?"

Comment: @Oddthinking - yep. I didn't think this was ambiguous in any way, sorry. Edited

Comment: Not everyone knows who Rasputin was, or who Boney M was, or what their song was. Added context.

Comment: @Oddthinking - context is fine, but since the "main" source of the claim is the song lyrics, i'd rather keep the title true to the claim wording.

Comment: The song takes poetic licence: "Russia's greatest love machine"? It is hard to argue that it makes clear claims. But the rumour is wider spread than that - it is notable, without having to rely on the song as its "main" source.

Comment: @Oddthinking - there was historical basis for the quoted claim in your comment, actually, but I suspect elaborating on it is a bit beyond the site's TOS.

Comment: Question I'd like to see some time: was Rasputin hard to kill?

Answer (score 3):

We will probably never know. No evidence.

Historians will normally stress that what's important is not whether claims about (im-)morality of rulers are factually true, but whether people actually **believe** that these claims are true. Popular rumours about the Romanov family during 1WW played a substantial part in the overthrow of the regime in 1917.

[Orlando Figes](http://www.orlandofiges.com/orlando.php), A Russian Revolution Scholar writes in his 2014 book *Revolutionary Russia, 1891-1991*:

> Similar credence was given to the rumours of sexual scandals at the
>   court. It was said that the Empress was the mistress of Rasputin and
>   the lesbian lover of Anna Vyrubova, her lady-in-waiting, who took part
>   in orgies with them both. Alexandra’s ‘sexual corruption’ became a
>   kind of metaphor for the diseased condition of the monarchy. Similar
>   pornographic tales about Marie Antoinette and the ‘impotent Louis’ had
>   circulated on the eve of the French Revolution in 1789. None of these
>   rumours had any basis in fact (Vyrubova was a dim-witted spinster
>   infatuated with the mystical powers of Rasputin and medically
>   certified to be a virgin by a special commission appointed to
>   investigate the charges against her in 1917). But the point of the
>   rumours was not their truth or untruth: it was their power to mobilize
>   an angry public against the monarchy. In a revolutionary crisis it is
>   perceptions and beliefs that really count. Without this ‘atmosphere’ –
>   created out of gossip, half-truths, facts and fabrications, bits of
>   information from the press which were then distorted into fantasies –
>   it is impossible to understand the ‘revolutionary mood’ or the ways in
>   which the revolution turned on the interpretation of hearsay and
>   events.

Source: Revolutionary Russia, 1891-1991: A Pelican Introduction

Comment: Do you have a source for "no evidence"?